# How can let labels no overlap just like indicator name label in the right?

Tags: pine-script

I use label.new to indicator the line of crypto name.
But it mixed together, and how can I let label no overlap?
thanks for help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScWAI.png)

Answer (score -1):

Try using `label.style_label_left` with the `style` argument in `label.new`.

```
label l = label.new(bar_index,close,"Label",style=label.style_label_left)
label.delete(l[1])
```

This way it won't overlap a plot that has the same `y` location.

Comment: thanks, it solved a lot.but cannot like tradingview's no overlap completely.